# what are Differencees between ViewDidDisappear and ViewDidUnload in ios?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

What is the Difference between ViewDidDisappear and ViewDidUnload
when did they call
if i'm using the navigation controller and go to another page why ViewDidUnload do not calls ViewDidDisappear calls.
How exactly we can know that ViewDidUnload is being called?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`viewDidUnload` is deprecated as of iOS6.0 and is never called, which the other answerers to this question have ignored. Don't implement this method any more. `viewDidDisappear` is called when the view controller's view has been removed from its superview.

Comment: Ya that's what i was searching for thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

- **ViewDidLoad** - Called when you create the class and load from xib.
  Great for initial setup and one-time-only work
- **ViewWillAppear** - Called right before your view appears, good for
  hiding/showing fields or any operations that you want to happen every
  time before the view is visible. Because you might be going back and 
  forth between views, this will be called every time your view is
  about to appear on the screen
- **ViewDidAppear** - Called after the view appears - great place to start 
  an animations or the loading of external data from an API.
- **ViewWill/DidDisappear** - Same idea as the WillAppear.
- **ViewDidUnload/Dispose** - Available to you, but usually not necessary
  in Monotouch. In objective-c, this is where you do your cleanup and
  release of stuff, but this is handled automatically so not much you
  really need to do here.

[There's great documentation on apple's site here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)